# Real analysis: Elias Zakon vs. Mark Bridger (vs. something else)

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I've been re-learning real analysis on my own after 15+ years because I'm planning to return to academia for a CS degree. I've been working through Real Analysis I by Elias Zakon (http://www.trillia.com/zakon-analysisI.html). But then I've found out about Real Analysis by Mark Bridger which is advertised as an alternative and a more modern constructivist approach. I started to have doubts and after browsing this site for advice and learning about textbooks by Tao, Rudin, and Apostol I got completely lost and frustrated. I guess my main question is: Is Real Analysis by Elias Zakon any good? And if not, to what textbook should I switch for self-study?

Comment: For that it's worth, thank you for the references. I've never heard of these books

Comment: If you look at the introduction of Zakon and its exercises, with their hints, you will see why this books stood out: 4 volumes
Basic, Analysis I, Analysis II and Theory of numbers. Those books will pave the way to anything else in math. However one cannot learn  without going through these exercises.
I have spent a lot of time with Zakon, and my life is easier now. Unfortunately you will hardly heard about this books, and i do not know why! Perhaps because they tackle anything, more then what teacher usually include in their courses..